# npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.11 cannot install the ionic 2 beta

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Please whenever i run this command `npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.11` it returns to me errors. 
I want to install ionic version 2 beta for specific requirement.
If beta.11 doesn't work. Can you suggestion me another version of ionic 2 beta to install. My project requires ionic 2 beta.

Best Regards
Here is the error encountred:

[image]

Comment: walk throw this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-projects-updating-to-beta-4/49054/5 may help

Comment: @Edison Thanks for answering this issue. I am in ionic version 2.2.2 and whenever i run the command it returns to me errors.

Comment: run commands in administrator mode and check once

Comment: Already Admin. thanks for the answer